# Will signing out of iCloud in browsers wipe my iPhone?

Tags: icloud, iphone

I want the information in my apps on my iPhone 5s to be erased since the phone has been lost.

If I choose the option "Sign out of iCloud on all Browsers", would this help or erase all my data on my iPhone?

Comment: Be careful - if you click a setting and you don't understand what it does, you could remove the control you have over the device. Also - it is best to follow [ask] so that people know exactly what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

No. In iCloud, you need to select your lost iPhone 5S and then choose "Erase Content". You can also use an iOS device to do the same thing by logging into your iCloud account there and choosing to remove all the content from your iPhone. The phone will be wiped after it connects to the Internet.

After the phone is wiped, you will **not** be able to view it in iCloud anymore. If you want to retain it in iCloud, you need to "lock" it instead. I recommend that your review [Apple's article in iCloud's security features](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2701?locale=en_US) so you have a better idea of what will occur.

Signing out of iCloud in all browsers would make sure no one else is logged into your iCloud account *through* a browser.